# reading txt file from url (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to read .txt files from external links the user provides, so I can later use them in an app. For now I'm just trying to show them in a div (.output). I got so far, and now I got stuck, don't really know how to proceed.

```js
function getText(url){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            if (type.indexOf("text") !== 1) {
                return request.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
}

$(".url-input").change(function() {
getText($(".url-input").value);
});
```

```css
.output {
width:500px;
height:500px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
    <title>Ugh</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
      
   </head>
   
 <body>
 <div class="output"></div>
 <input class="url-input" type="url">
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery on your web page, so you might want to try using jQuery's AJAX handling instead of JavaScript's native methods; it's a lot easier to work with IMHO: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `$(".url-input").value` is wrong, `value` is a DOM property. Use jQuery's `.val()` or use the native DOM object

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler to see exactly what you're getting back from the URL?

Comment: @dustmouse sadly, I have no idea what you mean by Fiddler, gonna go google

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript get (notice you have to input the file name with the extension (.txt):
just change the value to val():

```
$(".url-input").change(function() {
    getText($(".url-input").val());
});
```

jQuery get:
replace all the javascript with these few lines:

```
$(".url-input").change(function() {
    $.get($(this).val(), function( data ) {
        $('.output').html(data);
    });
});
```

This is much better option, because the Ajax Get is an asynchronous call, so you want to update the output value on the callback.

By the way, you should do some validation on that use input before you make the Ajax call. Also, to remove the need to add the ".txt" in the input change it to:

```
$(".url-input").change(function() {
    $.get($(this).val()+'.txt', function( data ) {
        $('.output').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: now I'm getting: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://topdeckandwreck.com/stackOverflow/Susti-2015.2.4-7949902-FRFFRFFRF.txt.txt. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: I can open the .txt file in my browser without problems though (by pasting the url into the browser url)

Comment: Do you have the text file locally? try it on your server. if you are trying to load a remote file, it is not so simple, as you can see you are getting a cross domain issue. if it was a json file you could use a jsonp call. so, let's start with this - are the text files on the same server as the script?

Comment: Hey, I used to have local files, and just open them with the (input type="file") button, but now I want to be able to link to a .txt file on different servers, mainly so users can upload their files, then link to them. Should I just be uploading files to my server trough the input type file and then loading them from there? Guess I need ajax for that as well, right?